# Archive by custom post type and custom date field

Tags: pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives, events

I have created a **custom post type** called **'events'** and **custom date field** called **'event_date'** .

I was able to create  archive list for custom post type using 
[this awesome plugin](https://github.com/jacklenox/archives-for-custom-post-types)

This plugin allowed me create archives list url in this format : www.example.com/2015/11/events/

Till this point every thing worked perfectly.

But I wanted to created **archives by 'event_date'** unlike usual by published date, so made some changes in the above mentioned plugin and was able to create an archive list by 'event_date'.

I am unable to view posts when I click on the link :
www.example.com/2016/09/events/

Now when I am writing this question the month is november so for events in november it returns correct posts.

I have used pre_get_post to get event by 'event_date' but it still returns posts by published date. Here is my code to get the posts:

```
function custom_events_query( $query ) {

    if (  $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive && !is_admin()&& is_post_type_archive('events') && $query->query_vars['m']!='') {

        $query->set( 'post_type', 'events' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'post_per_page', 10 );
        unset($query->query_vars['year']);
        unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
        unset($query->query_vars['day']);

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'value' =>  array(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($query->query_vars['m'].'01')),date('Y-m-d',strtotime($query->query_vars['m'].'31'))) ,
                'compare' => '>=',
            )
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_events_query' );
```

Why does it still return posts by published date when I have

```
unset($query->query_vars['year']); 
unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
```

[Here is a link](http://pastebin.com/qW1Kfndd) to the output which i get when trying to open: http://www.example.com/2016/08/events/

I have started using wordpress very recently and I am not sure about using pre_get_post correctly. It would be great if you could help me with this final step.
Thanks in advance. Forgive me for trying to explain my entire journey through events, I just wanted to make sure I was doing things correctly.

Comment: Have you checked that your `pre_get_posts` function passes all of the `if` conditions?

Comment: Yes it passes all the conditions.

Comment: `var_dump( $wp_query )` in the template, it will show you the value of all query vars and the SQL query being sent to the database.

Comment: I have added a link to the show the output which I get now.

Comment: There seems to be some missing data, I don't see the SQL. I also see the `m` query var is still set, which is probably causing a conflict.

Comment: Thanks @Milo as you suggested : m query var caused the conflict. Thank you very much. I have successfully created events functionality now. Wohooo!!!!!

Comment: Add your working code as an answer and accept it so that it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo) for helping me through this. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
function custom_events_query( $query ) {

    if (  $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive && !is_admin()&& is_post_type_archive('events') && $query->query_vars['m']!='') {

        $query->set( 'post_type', 'events' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        $query->set( 'post_per_page', 10 );
        unset($query->query_vars['year']);
        unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
        unset($query->query_vars['day']);

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'value' =>  array(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($query->query_vars['m'].'01')),date('Y-m-d',strtotime($query->query_vars['m'].'31'))) ,
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            )
        );
        unset($query->query_vars['m']);
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_events_query' );
```

All I had to do is unset the query_vars['m']. Since I needed it to construct my meta_query I unset it only after I was done using it i.e just before `$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );`

I hope this helps someone.