# Making a archive gallery page for a custom post type which already has an archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have created an events custom post type archive by custom date field and completed all related pages successfully.

It has :

1. Archive page in the format : http://www.example.com/events/
2. Archive by month (event date and not published date) list and having proper url structuring like: http://www.example.com/2015/11/events/

You can check [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207717/archive-by-custom-post-type-and-custom-date-field/207909#207909) which I asked recently to understand my approach towards creating the events which is archived by **custom date field**.

I created events archive page using `get_template_part('content', get_post_type());` in archive.php page.

So the archive page name is `content-events.php`

Now I am not able to find a clean solution to make a gallery page for events which has:

1. Images and name of the events listed by month.
2. Archive list with some proper url structuring like : www.example.com/2015/11/gallery/events , www.example.com/2015/10/gallery/csrevents
3. Suppose there are 2 types of events

   - events - /gallery/events
   - csrevents -/gallery/csrevents
     And a common url /gallery
4. How can I route all three url's to same template file and then conditionally load the data based on url

I thought of following approach but I am not sure if it will be the correct way:

1. To create a page programmatically using `wp_insert_post` and setting the page template to `template-gallery.php` and setting the slug as `events-gallery`
2. Using `WP_Query` to get events post type by month in this page.
3. Changing the url format to www.example.com/2015/11/gallery/events/in [this plugin](https://github.com/jacklenox/archives-for-custom-post-types) when the page name is template-gallery.php
4. Using `pre-get-post` to highjack the url www.example.com/2015/11/gallery/events to get the month and year and setting post type as events. This shall return the posts for this month and year.

The main problem here is that I am trying to have 2 archive pages for same post type and this is making the process dirty.

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: the cleanest way would probably be to add some extra rewrite rules. If you look at that plugin where the rules are generated, you can add some extras to handle `/gallery/` at the end of each, and set your own query var so you can identify those requests when templates are loaded.

Comment: Thank @Milo for the quick reply. Am I correct on the templating part or I there is a way to do it through archives.php by adding some conditional tags. Is there a way I can make this page go through the archive page and use get_template_part so that I can reuse the archive page design for other custom post type gallery pages also.

Comment: You can force whatever template you want for any type of request by using the [template filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) and checking query vars or conditional tags in there.

Comment: @Milo I have been trying but not getting through. How do I open up a common template for /events/gallery , csrevents/gallery  and allevents/gallery where allevents is not even a custom post type. And then conditionally load data based on the url.

Comment: I am stuck at step one itself i.e to open up a template on click of /events/gallery or csrevents/gallery . I tried using archive_template filter but  I realized that events/gallery will never goes through it. Please help me.

Comment: What are those requests? If you `var_dump($wp_query)` you should be able to identify what it is. You can also use the generic [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), which will fire for every type of request.